# modify array in loop

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
$arraya = array('a','b','c');
foreach($arraya as $key=>$value)
{
    if($value == 'b')
    {
        $arraya[] = 'd';
        //print_r($arraya);    //$arraya now becomes array('a','b','c','d')
    }
    echo $key.' is '.$value."\n";
}
```

and it will get:

```
0 is a
1 is b
2 is c
```

And I wonder why `3 is d` doesn't show up??

Comment: possible duplicate of [change initial array inside the foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348077/change-initial-array-inside-the-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Note: Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. foreach has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the foreach without resetting it.

Comment: +1 In other words: dont try to change the array whilst in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: `foreach(&$arraya as $key=>$value)` is not valid syntax in PHP 5.3.

Comment: @janmoesen: I've removed that part - it's not something I've tried before tbh.

Comment: @janmoesen: It has to be `foreach($arraya as $key=>&$value)`. The value has to be referenced. But with this you can only change the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arraya = array(a,b,c);
foreach($arraya as $key=>$value)
{
    if($value == b)
    {
        $d = 'd';
        array_push($arraya, $d);
        //print_r($arraya);    //$arraya now becomes array(a,b,c,d)
    }
    print_r($arraya);
    echo $key.' is '.$value."\n";
}
```

you will need to print the whole array not the individual elements one by one.
you will get your result only when you print $arraya

if $arraya had 'd' already in it then it would have printed easily.

Answer (score 0):

it's the same reason that the else in the following statement will not be executed...

```
int a = 1;
if(a == 1){
   a = 0;
}
else{
   //print something;
}
```

your foreach deals with an array as it is when it is evaluated by the foreach clause.