# Is it safe to add new keys to an array while iterating over it?

Tags: php

For example, is this safe?

```
foreach($opps_data as $k=>$v) {
    $opps_data[$k.'_mixed'] = WXU::MixedCase($v);
}
```

It seems to work fine. Does that mean PHP makes a copy of the array before it starts looping?

Comment: if you wanted to add elements which you then used in the loop you need to do this `while(list($element_key, $element) = each($elements)){`

Comment: possible duplicate of [change initial array inside the foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348077/change-initial-array-inside-the-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `foreach` loop operates on a copy of original array. More info about internal behaviour of `foreach` can be found in [this great blog](http://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

`foreach()` uses iterators. Array is called then iterator is used for pointing to array which was called.
In this case `$opps_data` is called only once. Iterator will not reference original array it will be working on copy of `$opps_data` which was called.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question. I'm familiar with iterators, but if the iterator references the original array, then this would still be a dangerous operation.