# PHP - array_push in foreach loop of the same array doesn't update the array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I need to be able to echo 1 and 2 with an array_push in the same foreach loop of that array.

```
<?php
$arr = array('1');

foreach ($arr as &$arr_number) {
   echo "$arr_number\n"; //this print 1
   array_push($arr, '2');
}

foreach ($arr as &$arr_number) {
   echo "$arr_number\n"; //this print 1 and then 2
}
?>
```

EDIT:
Solved it myself by not using a foreach but a while loop

```
    <?php
    $arr = array('1');

 while ( list($key, $value) = each($arr) ) {
    echo "$value\n";

    if ( !in_array('2', $arr) ) {
       array_push($arr, '2');
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: unable to understand question. can you please elaborate?

Comment: What you're trying to do?

Comment: What is the aim for using references in your code?

Comment: @zerkms: yeah, probably no point in using references... doesn't matter, code still doesn't work with foreach without references

Answer (score 3):

> I need to be able to echo 1 and 2 with an array_push in the same
>   foreach loop of that array.

Implode it.

```
<?php
$arr = array('1');

foreach ($arr as &$arr_number) {

   array_push($arr, '2');
   echo implode(' ',$arr); //"prints" 1 2
}
```

Comment: would that not be an infinite loop ?

Comment: you're pushing an variable into an array which you're looping through. I thought that the iterator would detect the newly added item and thus continuing the loop. But it's an instance at that moment. My excuses for my confusion.

Comment: @KarelG The `implode` function above simply concatenates all the array values together with a space. It won't affect the loop. Also the iterator **does not** detect the newly added value which is why the OP is receiving only `1` as output.

Comment: @KarelG No, it's not. see the first answer of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348077/change-initial-array-inside-the-foreach-loop

Comment: @KarelG yes that would be an infinite loop, I had to kill PHP :) I added the check in_array to make it work

Comment: @Shankar not what I'm looking for, what if the '2' is generated dynamically, first time it's a '2', then a '3' and so on

Comment: @Zurd, The question was pretty unclear on the first place and the above answer did its justice. The above code **will not** run into an infinite loop unless you add an item in the beginning of your array.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran array_push always adds to the end of the array and increases the length. (http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: @bouscher, I didn't mean the `array_push`. Can you see this `<?php
$arr = array('1');` , If any new element was added there, then the above solution will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Can you elaborate on the reasons? Why is the only thing, that prevents this code from looping infinitely the fact that the initial array only contains one item? To me this is counter intuitive. Does it have to do with the internal array pointer pointing to the end of the array right from the beginning?