# How could I modify an array inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this code but does not work.

```
$arr1 = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3);

foreach ($arr1 as $x) {
    $m = array_shift($arr2);

    //at this point, $arr2 remains unchanged, why?

    continue;
}
```

$arr2 does not seem to change within and in between iterations. Any insights will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [change initial array inside the foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348077/change-initial-array-inside-the-foreach-loop)

Comment: I Cannot Reproduce your issue; this question is Off-topic.

Comment: _"at this point, $arr2 remains unchanged, why?"_ What evidence do you have that `$arr2` is unchanged? Please post code that indicates this definitively.

Answer (score 0):

This does work. This code here:

```
$arr1 = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3);

foreach ($arr1 as $x) {
    $m = array_shift($arr2);

    print_r($arr2);

    continue;
}
```

Will print this:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( )
```